# Cannot open port on AWS Amazon Ubuntu

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, port

I use AWS Ubuntu Instance and try to open port 8080.
This is my "Security Groups" settings:
[image: AWS]

I have added port 8080 to iptables

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Firewall is disabled

```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

Nmap:

```
nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-04 17:10 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00012s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

Only port 22 (SSH) is enabled.
Do you have any ideas how I can open 8080 port?

Answer (score 2):

Are you running any service on port 8080?

Looks to me like no service is actually running on that port.

Try running `netcat -l 8080` then attempt to connect to it to validate that it is running.

Comment: My mistake. I had to start service on this port but it's still shows closed on online port checkers.

nmap:
22/tcp   open  ssh
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

netcat: Address already in use

Comment: My IP: ec2-18-184-30-11.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com